# directory paths in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I am trying to pass a series of "correct" paths as strings to a mySQL database column.

Since multiple instances may be UPDATEd at the same time, I have chosen to use MySQL's CASE syntax, though I am not overly familiar with it.

The result passes "0" to the database, instead of the string.

I have seen numerous examples using integers as the cases, but I need to use strings. I think this is giving me my grief.

Can the SO community have a look and see where the issue may be?

Here is the echoed SQL from the debug line above:

```
UPDATE linksUpdates

 SET newTarget = CASE 

  WHEN hitMissed = '/dir/dir/misLink1'         THEN newTarget = 'dir/home' 
  WHEN hitMissed = '/dir/dir/misLink2'         THEN newTarget = 'photos' 
  WHEN hitMissed = '/dir/dir/anotherBadLink'   THEN newTarget = 'dir/home' 
  END 
 WHERE misdirect IN (
   '/dir/dir/misLink1',
   '/dir/dir/misLink2',
   '/dir/dir/anotherBadLink'
       )
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Once you learn about those, you'll hopefully know why your query is wrong.

Comment: Am I vulnerable to SQL injection if there are no text fields?

Comment: injection has absolutely NOTHING to do with the types/quantity of your db fields, and everything to do with how you include "outside" data in your query string

Comment: Okay. So, I will remove the data from the POST array, sanitize it, and then submit it. Will this change the question that I asked?

Comment: Fabricator, I changed the variable builder to this:

$assignmentCases .= "WHEN '$key' THEN '$value' ";
$assignmentRefs .= "'$key',";

Now it passes (does not die), but it does not UPDATE the column.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Alright. I'm going to have a beer, enjoy my weekend, then take this up on Monday. I'll post here to let you know how it goes.

Comment: I have simplified my question above to focus on the mySQL. Rest assured, the data being sent to the mySQL database is clean. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `THEN` in your `CASE` statement doesn't need (or want) the column name. You're already specifying this before you open the `CASE`.

```
UPDATE linksUpdates

 SET newTarget = (CASE 

  WHEN hitMissed = '/dir/dir/misLink1'         THEN 'dir/home' 
  WHEN hitMissed = '/dir/dir/misLink2'         THEN 'photos' 
  WHEN hitMissed = '/dir/dir/anotherBadLink'   THEN 'dir/home' 
  END)
 WHERE misdirect IN (
   '/dir/dir/misLink1',
   '/dir/dir/misLink2',
   '/dir/dir/anotherBadLink'
       )
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, ydaetsk. The parentheses do not work however. The SQL returned an error. Thoughts?

Comment: I wanted you to paste the actual error you're getting but I've just realised that I'm being stupid. My original answer had a parenthesis in the wrong place and I hadn't realised but apparently you don't even NEED parentheses around the `CASE`. Instead your problem is that you are trying to state the column name in your `CASE` when you've already specified it before your `CASE` statement begins.

Comment: Technically, you are correct. I could make it work by doing this: 1. adding the search term beside the CASE: "SET newTarget = CASE hitMissed", then 2. removing both the search term and the updated field from the list of cases: "WHEN '$key' THEN '$value'" (single quotes necessary, "$" variables from php foreach loop), 3. the END and WHERE were just fine in the original, adding no new parentheses to my original.

Comment: I updated your answer with the result that is working in the field, and I will approve the answer for posterity. Thanking you for your help.